# Why Assembly load error occured on IIS publish

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, system.reflection

I have created an extension method to find my interface implementations in my asp.net core web api project.

```
    public static List<Type> FromAssembliesMatching<TType>(this AppDomain currentDomain, string searchPattern)
    {
        var referencedPaths = Directory.GetFiles(currentDomain.BaseDirectory, "*.dll").ToList();

        var assemblies = referencedPaths.Select(path => currentDomain.Load(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(path)));

        var types = assemblies.SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes().Where(t =>
                typeof(TType).IsAssignableFrom(t)
                && !t.IsInterface
                && !t.IsAbstract))
            .ToList();

        return types;
    }
```

For example, IMyInterface implemented types are found. This works while developing application.

But when I published it on iis.

```
System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'C:\publish\api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll'.
```

The extension method tring to load all dlls. I think c# generated dlls cause errors. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

That's expected.

Due to the deployment approach you use (self-contained), `dotnet publish` not only copies all your managed assemblies, but also native dependencies, like `api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll`. Those native dependencies cannot be loaded into app domain via reflection, so the exception is perfectly normal.

You have several options to resolve it though,

- Catch the exception and ignore it.
- Or proactively check if the dll is native or managed by using [PEFile class and related](https://www.fuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent/2.0.54/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent.dll/PEFile/PEHeader?code=true#P%3APEFile.PEHeader.IsManaged).